# CSS, ul creating a white space on bottom of page

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a ul to show info on the bottom of my page, but it creates a huge white space on the bottom.

I'd like for my bottominfo to not be part of the first 100% of the screen height, so that the user has to scroll down.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 150%;
}
.bottomInfo ul li {
  display: block;
  padding: 7px;
  color: #c0c0c0;
}
.bottomInfo ul li:first-child {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  bottom: 11px;
  font-size: 100%;
}
.bottomInfo ul {
  top: 20%;
  left: 10%;
  margin: 5px;
  position: absolute;
}
.bottomInfo {
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  top: 100%;
  background-color: #003047;
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 75%;
}
```

```html
<div class="bottomInfo">
  <ul>
    <li>About</li>
    <li>Newsletter</li>
    <li>Updates</li>
    <li>About the organisation</li>
    <li>Complaints</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I would guess you want a `margin-top:100vh` in your DIV, rather than your absolute positioning.

Comment: Create a snippet please, as we need to see the rest of the html. Also, maybe setting the body like this cause some issues `height: 150%;` ... and `position: absolute;` need `position: relative;` on its parent ...

Comment: The height of your bottomInfo is 50% of screen height, so you need to change strategy and correct your code. We can't give an answer without seeing the full source.

Comment: Appears to work for me

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with you specified body height to 150% so its taking huge height. Remove height from body it will take auto height and pushes the your bottom info below viewport.

Here is the body CSS should look like.

```
body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
width: 100%; 
height: 100%; //or remove it
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;

}
.placeholder{height:1000px;width:90%;border:5px solid pink;}
.bottomInfo ul li {
  display: block;
  padding: 7px;
  color: #c0c0c0;
}
.bottomInfo ul li:first-child {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  bottom: 11px;
  font-size: 1em;
}
.bottomInfo ul {
  top: 20%;
  left: 10%;
  margin: 5px;
 
}
.bottomInfo {
  position:fixed;
  bottom:0;left:0;
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #003047;
  font-size: .75em;
}
<div class="placeholder"></div>
<div class="bottomInfo">
  <ul>
    <li>About</li>
    <li>Newsletter</li>
    <li>Updates</li>
    <li>About the organisation</li>
    <li>Complaints</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

here you go.
I have changed some things, but it should all be clear.

Cheers.